# Procedimiento almacenado insertar en MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Crear un procedimiento almacenado que el `id` `auto incremente` , lo realicé en `SQLSERVER` pero no se como hacerlo en `MySQL`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insersertar
(@nombemple varchar(30))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@num int;
DECLARE
 @id char(5);
SELECT @num = COUNT(*) FROM empleado;
SELECT @id='E' + right('000' + cast(@num + 1 as varchar), 4);
INSERT INTO empleado VALUES (@id, @nombemple);
```

Comment: Estimado en el mundo perfecto su consulta seria valida, pero si por casualidad de la vida un registro es borrado el hecho de hacer un SELECT COUNT(*) PODRIA DUBLICAR UNA LLAVE,

Answer (score 1):

Estoy algo fuera de forma con mysql pero prueba con lo siguiente :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insersertar
(IN nombemple VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

    DECLARE NUM INT;
    DECLARE ID CHAR(5);

    SET NUM = COUNT(*) FROM EMPLEADO;
    SET ID = 'E' + right('000' + cast(@num + 1 as varchar), 4);
    INSERT INTO EMPLEADO VALUES (ID,EMPLEADO);  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo , añadiré una donde emplearé dos variables definidas como en su procedimiento en `SQL`,  `num` tendrá el valor de las filas que hay actualmente en su tabla y `id` el valor **`generado`**

Para generar el nuevo código se usó la función [LEFT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left)  , que devolverá la cantidad de caracteres a la `izquierda` especificados en el segundo parámetro.

```
SELECT LEFT('holamundo', 4); // retona 'hola'
```

Teniendo esto en consideración , el segundo parámetro será la cantidad `total` de caracteres aceptados por la columna en su tabla  `(5)`, **`menos`** la cantidad de caracteres obtenido con la función  [CHAR_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) *(no estoy seguro si sea la mejor opción de obtener la cantidad de un int)* del valor devuelto por la función `count` , todo esto se concatenará con el valor de `num` , finalmente se realiza el `Insert` de los valores.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertsertar(IN nombemple  varchar(80) )
BEGIN 
    DECLARE num int;
    DECLARE id  char(5);
    SET num = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM empleado); 
    SET id = CONCAT(LEFT('E0000', 5-CHAR_LENGTH(num)),num);
    INSERT INTO empleado values (id ,nombemple);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola en mysql nos podemos valer de un alter table para que nos apoye a realizar el auto incremental de forma automatica.

primero debes de saber el numero maximo más uno

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 as resultado FROM empleado;
```

Despues realizas la ateracion de la tabla asignandole el valor resultante

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = (resultado);
```

De esa manera el Primary Key siempre se incrementara de forma automatica y no tienes que realizar una consulta extra

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insersertar (IN nombemple VARCHAR(30)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE id CHAR(5) DEFAULT 'E0001';
    SELECT CONCAT('E', RIGHT(CONCAT('000', MID(MAX(libre), 2, 5) + 1), 4))
    FROM (SELECT 'E0001' libre UNION SELECT MAX(id) libre FROM empleado) l INTO @id;
    INSERT INTO empleado VALUES (@id, @nombemple);
END
```

Eso respondería tu pregunta, pero tiene ciertos problemas:

Cuando se llega al máximo permitido por tu clave (`E9999`), el siguiente que te propondrá será el `E0000` (porque debería ser el `E10000` pero, al limitar la clave a 4 dígitos y una letra, no se podrá representar correctamente.

### ¿Por qué funciona?

```
SELECT MAX(id) libre FROM empleado
```

obtiene el máximo actual (y si no hay registros devolverá `NULL`)

```
SELECT 'E0001' libre UNION SELECT MAX(id) libre FROM empleado
```

devuelve dos registros: `E0001` y, el máximo que encontró antes (si no había registros, será entonces `E0001` y `NULL` ... si sí había registros devolverá, digamos, `E0001` y `E0100`)

Lo siguiente será elegir el máximo entre los dos, sumarle uno, y devolverlo con el formato esperado:

```
SELECT CONCAT('E', RIGHT(CONCAT('000', MID(MAX(libre), 2, 5) + 1), 4))
    FROM (...)
```

Lo que hace ésta última sección es `MAX(libre)` para obtener el máximo de los 2 que se obtuvieron antes (si no había registros, será `E0001`, que compara mayor a `NULL` ... si sí había, elegirá el mayor entre los dos: digamos que eligió `E0100`)

A eso le hace `MID( ... , 2, 5)` para quedarse con `0100` y le suma 1, obteniendo, ya numérico, `101`.

Por último: `CONCAT('E', RIGHT(CONCAT('000', ... ), 4))` le pone `000` delante al `101` (`000101`), selecciona los 4 de la derecha (`0101`) y agrega una '`E`' adelante: `E0101`

Si bien ésto responde la pregunta, mucho cuidado porque **jamás debería usarse en producción**.

No es suficiente decir que el lugar donde se usará nunca tendrá más de 10.000 empleados, porque basta con que por otro lado se ingrese al empleado con id `E9995` para que la cantidad posible desde ahí se reduzca a 5, o que la base de datos funcione el tiempo suficiente como para que al final roten 10.000 empleados ... renuncian, se contratan más, son despedidos, mueren, se contratan más ... y en poco tiempo alguien será el empleado `E9999`, y ésto no servirá más.